# Как с помощью Jquery или JavaScript сделать сравнение одного числа с многими?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть:

```
<input type="text" class="pl_all_filter" value="40">
```

И есть список блоков с цифрами:

```
<div>10</div>
<div>20</div>
<div>30</div>
<div>40</div>
<div>50</div>
<div>60</div>
```

При изменении значения в input нужно, чтобы с сайта скрывались блоки, у которых число меньше чем то, что написано в input.

```
$('.pl_all_filter').on('input',function(e){   
    var input_val = parseInt($(this).val());    
    $('.line_block_planirovki .simplebar-content > div').each(function() {  
        var pl_all = parseInt($(this).find('.all_pl_vn').text());
});
```

Вот какой код на jQuery получилось написать.

По логике:

1. берем то число, что в input,
2. обходим все div, берем числа с них,
3. и нужно как то сравнить одно число с множеством чисел,
4. и срыть те блоки, где значения меньше чем в input.

Comment: Не опубликовалось. Есть input type="text"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.pl_all_filter').on('input',function(e){   
  var input_val = +$(this).val();    
  $('.line_block_planirovki .simplebar-content > div').each(function() {  
    var pl_all = +$(this).find('.all_pl_vn').text();
    if (pl_all >= input_val)
      $(this).show();
    else
      $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Внутри `each` ключевое слово `this` будет указывать на конкретный `div`, нужно взять *у него* текст, и затем, например используя метод [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) скрыть или показать этот элемент.

Этот метод может принимать булевское значение, указывающее скрыть или показать элемент, поэтому в него можно просто передать результат сравнения, например

```js
$('.pl_all_filter').on('input', function(e) {
  var input_val = parseInt($(this).val());
  $('.simplebar-content > div').each(function() {
    var pl_all = parseInt($(this).text());

    $(this).toggle(input_val > pl_all);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="pl_all_filter" value="40">

<div class="simplebar-content">

  <div>10</div>
  <div>20</div>
  <div>30</div>
  <div>40</div>
  <div>50</div>
  <div>60</div>

</div>
```